# mongodb find greater than two dates

Tags: mongodb

My table name is `tbl1` and I want to find the greater than two dates :

```
db.getCollection('tbl1').find({
    "created" : { 
        "$gt" : "2016-04-09T08:28:47",
        "$gt" : "2016-04-09T08:34:38.000+0000"}
})
```

Only greater than date values.

can some one help me to resolve this.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. Also why do you have duplicate `$gt` operator in your query criteria?

Comment: What do you want to find greater than two dates. Documents? Or just which date is greater?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No idea why you have two clauses here, however the problem is you are applying a greater than to a text field.  You probably want something more along the lines of:

```
db.tbl1.find({
    $and:[
        {"created": {"$gt" : ISODate("2016-04-09T08:28:47") }},
        {"created": {"$gt" : ISODate("2016-04-09T08:34:38.000+0000"})}}
    ]
})
```